# Convert comma separated List<string> to List<Int>

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `List<string>` containing comma separated values, for example, each item looks like "123, 123, 123". Now, I want to convert this to a `List<int>`. How can I do that?

I have tried the following:

```
List<int> TagIds = parameters.AccidentId.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

But It says that:

> System.Collections.Generic.List does not contain a definition of "Split" accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found.

I define my AccidentId like this:

```
if (AccidentId != null && AccidentId.itemsSelected != null)
{
    parameters.AccidentId = new List<string>();
    foreach(var param in AccidentId.itemsSelected)
    {
        parameters.AccidentId.Add(param);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `parameters.AccidentId`  a list?

Comment: Seems like you are mixing with with `string.Split`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You effectively have a list of lists. Each `string` in your list is a comma separated list.

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten multiple sequences into a single list.

Something like:

```
parameters.AccidentId.SelectMany(s => s.Split(',').Select(int.Parse)).ToList()
```

This is roughly equivalent to

```
List<int> TagIds = new List<int>();

foreach(string s in parameters.AccidentId)
{
    string[] accidentIds = s.Split(',');
    foreach(string accidentId in accidentIds)
    {
        TagIds.Add(int.Parse(accidentId));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `parameters.AccidentId` is a `List<string>` and not a single `string` you can't use `String.Split` directly. But then you should rename the property anyway, f.e. `AccidentIdList`.

You could use this approach:

```
List<int> TagIds = parameters.AccidentId
    .SelectMany(id => id.Split(',').Select(int.Parse))
    .ToList();
```

or with `Array.ConvertAll`:

```
List<int> TagIds = parameters.AccidentId
    .SelectMany(id => Array.ConvertAll(id.Split(','), int.Parse))
    .ToList();
```